# WordPress Function to Add Page Views to API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

Good day WordPress developers

I have searched the internet looking for a WordPress Function that adds views from Jetpack from post endpoint. I am really finding it difficult because I am not a WordPress or PHP developer. I am only using it as my backend.

Alternatively, if I can create my own function that increases when a request is made I will love it.

Below is what I found from the internet but it didn't work for me.

```
function getPostViews($postID){
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    return "0 View";
}
return $count.' Views';
```

}

Comment: As the function name suggests, it gets the page views. What you have to do is, use the `update_post_meta` to update the value.

Comment: Please, I am not a php or WordPress developer. I really need this to be implemented. Can you help me with a code? Even if I have to pay to get it done.

Comment: I am not sure whether this code uses Jetpack views or it increases after every call. Please explain